# How to map all jiond data to single entity's propery in typeorm0.1.3

Tags: typeorm

I'm going to map my `employee` to it parent`employeeLeaveApprovers`entity as below environment. According to the document I have tried to use `leftJoinAndMapMany` method but I can't get the result as my expected

Default result data

```
"employeeLeaveApprovers": [
        {
            "id": 56,
            "createdAt": "2018-07-03T01:52:41.960Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-07-03T01:52:41.960Z",
            "createdBy": 1,
            "updatedBy": null,
            "state": 1,
            "version": 1,
            "approverId": 2,
            "required": true,
            "employee": {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "heng",
                "lastName": "Sopheak"
            }
        }
   ];
```

Expectation result

```
"employeeLeaveApprovers": [
        {
            "id": 56,
            "createdAt": "2018-07-03T01:52:41.960Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-07-03T01:52:41.960Z",
            "createdBy": 1,
            "updatedBy": null,
            "state": 1,
            "version": 1,
            "approverId": 2,
            "required": true,
            "firstName": "heng",
            "lastName": "Sopheak"
        }
   ];
```